# Terminal not logged in properly

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I'm having a bit of an odd issue with my terminal.

I'm used to the prompt being `Joosts-Macbook:~ Joost$` or something of that nature, but all of a sudden it displays a number I don't recognise: `n041134:~ Joost$`. I've added a screenshot of the Terminal below.

[image]

It does not seem to properly start bash either, since I can't do `./script.sh` to execute a script anymore - it requires me to type `bash script.sh` fully.

I'm on Mountain Lion 10.8. I'm not aware of anything I may have done that has caused this. I noticed it when I was trying to execute a shell script that did some find and replacing using `sed`, but it might have been like this earlier.

I tried the obvious fixes such as logging out and rebooting, but to no avail.

Comment: I was just told that this is in fact my host name, and by calling `hostname` the mystery was effectively solved. It turned out to be because I was connected to the university's network rather than my own, which changed my hostname.

The bash execution thing seems to be an unrelated coincidence..

Comment: You can answer your own question, which in this case seems appropriate.

Comment: You're right. I hadn't figured out the bash issue at the time, but I have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just told that this is in fact my host name, and by calling hostname the mystery was effectively solved. It turned out to be because I was connected to the university's network rather than my own, which changed my hostname.

The reason I couldn't properly execute shell scripts was an unrelated oddity. Apparently the permissions on the scripts I tried were not set properly. Coincidences made me link the two problems.